# Obtener cierto dia de la semana entre una rango de fechas en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Como Obtener las fechas de cierto día de la semana entre dos fechas. 
Ejemplo: Todos las fechas de los días lunes entre en rango del 2016-01-19 al 2016-02-19
Reultado:
2016-01-23
2016-01-30
2016-02-06
2016-02-13

Esto es lo que estoy haciendo pero estoy obteniendo los miercoles:

```
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE(REGISTRO DATE)
DECLARE @startdate datetime = '2016-01-19'
DECLARE @enddate datetime = '2016-02-19' ;with cte(col)
AS
(
SELECT @startdate
UNION ALL
SELECT col + 1
FROM cte
WHERE col <= @enddate
)
INSERT INTO @TEMP
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,0,col)% 7 = 0

SELECT * FROM @TEMP
```

Comment: em, deberías sacar el `WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,0,col)% 7 = 0` entonces

Comment: Pero si lo quito obtendre todos los días y solo necesito los lunes

Comment: Ah, ahora entiendo la pregunta. Entonces simplemente usa `WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY,col) = 'Lunes'`?

Comment: Veo puros lunes en las fechas que pusiste?

Comment: Lo siento puse mal el año, muchas gracias ya quedo

Answer (score 0):

**Utiliza la función `DATEPART` para filtrar según el día de la semana de la fecha.**

*Creo que el día depende de la configuración del servidor; en mi caso el día lunes retorna 1, pero haz pruebas para tu caso en particular.*

```
SELECT @startdate
UNION ALL
SELECT col + 1
FROM cte
WHERE col <= @enddate
)
INSERT INTO @TEMP
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE DATEPART(weekday,col) = 1;
```

Comment: Trate de hacerlo así y me sigue dando los miercoles

Comment: 2016-01-25
2016-02-01
2016-02-08
2016-02-15

Comment: @DanitzaAyala Esas fechas son del 2016. Todas las fechas son lunes, pero sus equivalentes del 2017 son miércoles; creo que te confundiste por eso.

Comment: lo siento ya vi mi error estaba poniendo 2016 y ocupaba los 2017